# MVC4 Extending WebSecurity.Login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a need to use (and validate) both UserName, and Business Name as part of a Login Process. So that my Login Form takes in CompanyId, UserId and Password.

This all works fine up to the point where I call

```
 if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
```

I can't just add in model.Companyid as a parameter to that method, I am hoping that it is just possible to extend this, or do I need to write my own Login method from scratch?

Answer (score 0):

Of course!

```
public class ExtendWebSecurity
{
    public static boolean Login(
        this WebSecurity ws,
        string username,
        string password,
        boolean persist,
        int companyId)
    {
        // Add your logic
        return ws.Login(username, password, persistCookie: persist);
    }
}
```

Note, this has not been tested.

Comment: Thanks, but not quite what I was asking (or so I thought!) I'd like to avoid having to do 2 seperate login calls, as I need to check that a username and companyId both match the password. I suspect, on reflection that I can't do this, and I need to create my own Login Method from Scratch.